# Find all the low numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, express

I have an application that takes in the values of ten questions through a select drop down box. The values are 1 - 5 for each drop down menu. When the user clicks on the submit button, I store all the values from the input boxes in an object and then send them to a $.post request route. Within this post request route on server side, I get the post data sent to server, and loop through an array of 'friends', subtracting each scores array to the scores the user selected. I need to record which friend has the lowest difference and send it back, but I cant figure out how to send back multiple 'friends' that may have the same lowest number.

frontside.js

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){


            var newProfile = {
                name: $('#name').val().trim(),
                photo: $('#link').val().trim(),
                scores: []
            };

            for(var x = 0; x < questions.length; x++){
                var num = parseInt($('select[name = "q' + (x+1) + '"]').val());
                newProfile.scores.push(num);
            }

            alert("Adding profile");

            var currentURL = window.location.origin;

            $.post(currentURL + "/api/friends", newProfile).done(function(data){
                console.log('data', data);
            });
```

server.js

```
var friends = require('./../data/friends.js');

app.post('/api/friends', function(req, res){
        console.log('hi')
        var person = req.body;
        var diff = [];
        var low = 0;
        var match = [];


        for(var x = 0; x < friends.candidates.length; x++){

            for(var i = 0; i < friends.candidates[x].scores.length; i++){

                var result = person.scores[i] - friends.candidates[x].scores[i];

                 if(result < 0){
                    var positive = result * (-1);
                    diff.push(positive);
                 }
                 else
                    diff.push(result);
            }

            //adding up the differences from each score
            var added = diff.reduce(function(a, b){
                return a + b;
            }, 0);

            //This is where I need to figure out how to store multiple lowest numbers of same value.
            if(x === 0){
                low = added;
                match.push(friends.candidates[x]);
            }
            else if(low > added){
                low = added;
                match[0] = friends.candidates[x];
            }

            finalNum.push(added);
            diff = []; 
        }

        friends.candidates.push(person);
        res.send(match);

    });
```

friends.js

```
exports.candidates = [
    {

        scores:[5,1,4,4,5,1,2,5,4,1]
    },
    {

        scores:[4,2,5,1,3,2,2,1,3,2]
    },
    {

        scores:[5,2,2,2,4,1,3,2,5,5]
    },
    {

        scores:[3,3,4,2,2,1,3,2,2,3]
    },
    {

        scores:[4,3,4,1,5,2,5,3,1,4]
    },
    {

        scores:[4,4,2,3,2,2,3,2,4,5]
    },
    {

        scores:[2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
    },
    {

        scores:[5,2,1,1,5,2,1,1,4,4]
    }];
```

Comment: sort by diff, then take all from the end that have the same diff.

Comment: the diff array is a temporary array that holds the difference of each subtracted numbers from the user scores array and the friends[x].scores array, it need to be reset after this is done, otherwise it will add onto the next persons difference scores

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// holds the minimum difference
var minDiff =  Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
// holds the list of friends with minimum difference
var minDiffFriends = [];
for(var x = 0; x < friends.candidates.length; x++){
            // variable to hold sum of differences
            var scoreSum = 0
            for(var i = 0; i < friends.candidates[x].scores.length; i++){

                var result = person.scores[i] - friends.candidates[x].scores[i];

                 if(result < 0){
                    result = result * (-1);
                 }
                 scoreSum += result;
            }

            if(scoreSum < minDiff) {
                minDiff = scoreSum ;
                //clear previous array
                minDiffFriends.length = 0;
                //add the current friend information
                minDiffFriends.push(friends.candidates[x]);
            }
            else if(scoreSum ==minDiff) {
                // store friend information 
                minDiffFriends.push(friends.candidates[x]);
            }
}
```